# C# split a textfile in two different listbox where initial lines of textfile appears in listbox1 and others appears in listbox2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I am stucked with displaying a textfile in two different listbox, the textfile contains list of links, and i want that, when someone upload the list, 1st 100 lines of textfile goes to listbox1 and the 2nd 100 lines goes to listbox2.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
                foreach (string line in text)
                {


                  listBox1.Items.Add(line);


                }
                listBox2.Items.Add(""); //

            }
            listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);
listBox2.SetSelected(0, true);
```

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: i wrote a user upload script and displaying it into one listbox , unable program it to display it into 2 list box, posting the codes. @Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int lineNum = 1;

foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(myFilePath))
{
    if (lineNum <= 100)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
    else
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(line);
    }

    lineNum++;
}
```